# How can we read artifactId, groupID and version from POM.xml in the Jenkins Job created using option Maven Project(need to pass to other job workspace

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have 2 jenkins job in which first job creates a jar which I am passing into the second job workspace but in order to use that jar, I need a way to find the name of that jar. I have been looking around a way to retrieve artifactId, groupId and version from POM.xml file which i then can use to locate the jar created by maven package/install goal.

All articles lead me only to the pipeline option to create a groovy script etc.